# Is there a way to "click" an element on a website using selenium by changing the attributes or values

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have a website that whenever I click a button with Selenium, the value obviously changes and a new button appears. And since having to click it and having to wait for the other button to appear, I wanted to know, whether it is possible to change the code so to speak to activate as well as the other button, instantly.

This is what I mean in terms of Elements

From this:

```
<input type="radio" name="surveyStart" form="formAccessApplication" value="DD" id="result0" data-id="0" class="result">
```

To this:

```
<input type="radio" name="surveyStart" form="formAccessApplication" value="DD" id="result0" data-id="0" class="result" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="0">
```

Second Button from this:

```
<input type="radio" name="nationality" form="formAccessApplication" value="DD" id="result1" data-id="3" class="result">
```

To this:

```
<input type="radio" name="nationality" form="formAccessApplication" value="DD" id="result1" data-id="3" class="result" data-gtm-form-interact-field-id="
```

I tried using execute script `By.XPATH`

```
radio = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='result1']")
driver.execute_script ("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-gtm-form-interact-field-id', '0')", radio)
```

But the result was no appearance of the second button

Answer (score 0):

It's generally a bad idea to try to manipulate the HTML on the page using JS, etc. It's a good way to get the site into a bad state and cause your script to fail. In this case, the easier way to achieve what you want is to click the first button, wait for the first button to go stale (indicating the button is being swapped out), and then find and click on the second button. Sample code is below.

```
e = driver.find_element(By.ID, "result0")
e.click()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.staleness_of(e))
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.ID, "result0")).click()
```